# Hypothesis test on a binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given that I am working on a binomial distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(10,p)$ and I am trying to construct a hypothesis test for $p$.  $H_0=0.5$ vs $H_1=0.55$.  Assume that we want a significance level 0.05.  How can I decide what is the value for $c$, the critical value? Also, Why can't we get a significance level of exactly 0.05?

Answer (score 0):

Significance is calculated based on the null distribution. Just find the closest thing you can get to upper and lower 2.5th percentiles *given* $p=0.5$. You won't get this exactly because the Binomial distribution is defined on the integers.